# Проверить значение массива в цикле foreach

Tags: php, циклы

Проблема следующая: есть необходимость в цикле foreach проверить значение массива на предыдущей итерации с текущим. Например: есть цикл:`<?php foreach ($_SESSION['orders'] as $orders): ?>` с помощью него заполняю данными какое-то поле: `<?php echo $orders["OrderID"];?>` , так вот мне нужно написать условие, которое проверяло бы это (текущее) значение `$orders["OrderID"]` со значением `$orders["OrderID"]` на предыдущей итерации - как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сохранить предыдущие значение в отдельной переменной в конце итерации, например, таким образом

```
<?php
  $prev_order_id = null;
  foreach ($_SESSION['orders'] as $orders) {
    ...
    if ($orders["OrderID"] != $prev_order_id)
    echo $orders["OrderID"];
    ...
    // В конце цикла сохраняем текущее значение OrderID 
    $prev_order_id = $orders["OrderID"];
  }
```